# How convert String like "["412","122"]" to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist

I'm getting a list of ids in a service formatted in an Array Stringified like "["111","232"...]".

I'm using:

```
ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(strListIds.split("[,\\s]+")));
```

but this didn't delete the first [ and the last ] of the string. I can remove this chars manually, but I'm asking this to know if there is a correct way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: You actually using a string in json format, you can use a JSON parser and get a array jsonway

Comment: Show us how you store/initialize `strListIds`!? That would be interesting and I assume not exactly as you wrote it in the question. Then how about parsing as something like `JSONArray`?

Comment: It comes from the server, in a string like "["111","232"...]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking to:

```
List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>(
        Arrays.asList(
                strListIds.substring(1, strListIds.length() - 1).split(",\\s")
        )
);// ["412","122"]
```

If you won't keep the `""`, then you need to replace them before the split:

```
.replace("\"", "")
```

---

But better I would use:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String[] arr = mapper.readValue(strListIds, String[].class);
List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr));// [412,122]
```

---

Bonus solution, using regex:

```
List<String> ids = Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\"")
        .matcher(strListIds)
        .results()
        .map(m -> m.group(1))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using streams:

```
List<String> ids =Arrays.stream(strListIds.substring(2, strListIds.length()-2).split(",")).map(value-> value.substring(1, value.length()-1)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have tried this , but just for your help you can try ObjectMapper which can help you to convert the values to desired type. 
There are specifically 2 methods which you can try especially the 2nd one
1) ObjectMapper.readValue(data,List.class)
2) ObjectMapper.convertValue(data, new TypeRefence>(){});

Here is the link for more detailed explaination
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial

Hope this helps